# Can the empty set be an index set?

Tags: logic, computability

I ran into a question, encountered in a computational course.

Could anyone tell me why the empty set $ \emptyset $ can be an index set?

My source is [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=SJvt8ELnMakC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=index+set+computation+E+even+number+is+no+index+set&source=bl&ots=HRxV823Gt-&sig=jR5qgZXpSLoXz0xN8hGTd9-AIc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5-gJVaizFu_jsATomoGIAQ&ved=0CFkQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=index%20set%20computation%20E%20even%20number%20is%20no%20index%20set&f=false)

Comment: @Woodface: this question is not related to elementary set theory, or any other kind of set theory; it is just about computability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've seen How I Met Your Mother, you might remember the episode when Barney is riding a motorcycle inside a casino, and when the security guards grab him he points out one simple thing: "Can you show me the rule that says you cannot drive a motorcycle on the casino's floor?".

Mathematics is quite similar. If there's nothing in the rules which forbids it, it's allowed.

Direct your attention to Definition 7.1.9 in that book, it says that an index set is a set of all indices of some family of computable [partial] functions/computably enumerable sets. The empty set is a set of computable functions, and the empty set is exactly its index set.

Comment: I never thought I'd see a HIMYM reference on MSE. Well done.

Comment: Well, pop culture references are always fun. :-)

Comment: can you say how the empty set is a set of computable functions?

Comment: @Dio: Can you show me the element of the empty set which is *not* a computable function? :-)

Comment: wow, get it. can i ask another question ?

Comment: @DioIli Because everything that *is* an element of $\emptyset$ is a computable function (or is a pop culture reference or anything else).  In particular, for *any* set, family, or collection $A$, you have $\emptyset \subset A$.

Comment: for example why  K is not index set ?  K={n : φ n (n)↓}?

Comment: @Dio: I'm not sure what you mean by $\downarrow$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila , In general When we say K is K={$x|x \in W_x$} see for W the OP books.

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura: Ah, so it's the same $K$ from the example. In which case, the solution is written explicitly in the book.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, maybe the questioner not familiar, it's not bad to explain it. anyway.

Comment: @Dio: The reason is that if you look at singletons, you can find some $e$ which is an index for $\{e\}$; then taking a different index for $\{e\}$ (which is of course possible), we obtain an index $e'$ such that $e'\notin W_{e'}=\{e\}$, so $e'\notin K$. So $K$ is not a set of *all* indices of something.